# Aggregating data over matching cell in rows and calculate difference in dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe:

`d = {'User': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'Date' : ['2017-10-21', '2017-10-24', '2017-10-29', '2017-09-30', '2017-10-23', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-03', '2017-11-03']} 
df = pd.Dataframe(data=d)`

which looks like:

`User    Date
A      2017-10-21
A      2017-10-24
A      2017-10-29
B      2017-09-30
B      2017-10-23
C      2017-10-31
C      2017-11-02
C      2017-11-03
C      2017-11-03`

What I want is adding another column to find the difference between dates of each user: starting from the earliest date (so difference is 0) to the next, and the next date to the date after that and so on.

The Dataframe would then look like:

`User    Date    Difference
A      2017-10-21    0
A      2017-10-24    3
A      2017-10-29    5
B      2017-09-30    0
B      2017-10-23    23
C      2017-10-31    0
C      2017-11-02    2
C      2017-11-03    1
C      2017-11-03    0`

Note: The users and the dates are already sorted in the original Dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), for convert timedeltas add [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
#if necessary sorting
#df = df.sort_values(['User','Date'])

df['Difference'] = df.groupby('User')['Date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
  User       Date  Difference
0    A 2017-10-21           0
1    A 2017-10-24           3
2    A 2017-10-29           5
3    B 2017-09-30           0
4    B 2017-10-23          23
5    C 2017-10-31           0
6    C 2017-11-02           2
7    C 2017-11-03           1
8    C 2017-11-03           0
```

Comment: I got an error: `TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: @panaceanoob - What is your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas version is 0.22.0

Comment: Are values datetimes in column Date? Try add `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` before.